# read the value of a label onchange of input field

Tags: reactjs

```
  handleChange: function() {  
  }; 
  render: function() {
      return (
          <label>inputdate</label>
          <input type="text" onchange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />         
          <label value="10/20/2018">Outputdate</label>                
      );
```

how can I read output date value on change of inputdate

Comment: Is the date value always hard coded in your real app? If not, where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the date is hardcoded in your component, then you don't need to get the value from the label. You just hardcode it in the `handleChange()` function as well.
2. If the date is not hardcoded in your component, then you should be passing it in as a prop. Here you also don't need to get it's value because you can access it directly with something like `this.props.outputdate`.

Comment: @ama Then you should have a similar `handleChange()` function for the outputdate. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: @ama What is the reason that you cannot do an onchange for output date?

Comment: lets assume we have an input field (inputdate) and a label called output date. now onchange of input date i should read the outputdate label value to do further calculation.please let me know if that doesn't make sense

Comment: Sure.. but let me know if it possible to do this using react